# What is this growing on my bamboo palm?

Tags: palm

[image]

I'm just hoping for clarification on what the green shoots are coming out on the lower stalks of my bamboo palm houseplant.  The upper part of the plant did not care for the trip home from IKEA and has died back with brown leaves that I've been trimming. These green shoots are coming out in the lower part of the plant and I hope it's a sign that the plant will survive and recover because it was gorgeous when I purchased it.

Answer (score 2):

These are the inflorescences that are the method to produce fruit for this member of the [Chamaedorea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaedorea) family. There are male and female flowers on separate plants. The spots on the growth eventually become fruit that are spherical and blackish.

When I was maintaining these plants I removed these promptly by tearing gently at the base.  If there was mealy bug anywhere around they would be attracted to the new growth.